# magento form submit handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, magento

We have a magento site that is using the WebForms2 plugin and ends up using something like the following generated code for a form:

**HTML**

```
<form action="http://example.com/magento/index.php/webforms/index/iframe" method="post" name="webform_2" id="webform_2" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="webforms-lg-test" target="webform_2_iframe">
  <input type="hidden" name="submitWebform_2" value="1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="webform_id" value="2"/>

  <div id="fieldset_0" class="fieldset fieldset-0 ">
    <ul class="form-list">
      <li class="fields ">
        <div id="field_11" class="field  type-text webforms-fields-11 webforms-fields-name">
          <label id="label_field11" for="field11">Name</label>
          <div class="input-box">
            <input type='text' name='field[11]' id='field11' class='input text ' style='' value="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons-set">
    <p class="required">* Required Fields</p>
    <button type="button" class="button" id="webform_2_submit_button" onclick="webform_2_submit()" title="submit">
      <span>
        <span>Submit</span>
      </span>
    </button>
    <span class="please-wait" id="webform_2_sending_data" style="display:none;">
      <img src="http://example.com/magento/skin/frontend/default/default/images/opc-ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending..." title="Sending..." class="v-middle"/>
      <span id="webform_2_progress_text">Sending...</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var webform_2 = new VarienForm('webform_2', 0);
var webform_2_submit = function(){
  var form = webform_2;
  if(form.validator && form.validator.validate()){
    form.submit();
    $('webform_2_submit_button').hide();
    $('webform_2_sending_data').show();
  }
};
```

The tricky part is that we have an additional tool that works with *all* forms. Previously we just had it hook into the forms submit handler, but this particular method that Magento/WebForms uses, does not trigger the submit handler.

An example of our tool's code:

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
for(i=0; i<forms.length; i++) {
  forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function() {
    alert('form submitted');
  } 
}
```

We were also using a jQuery approach, but pared it down to reduce dependancies. It also did not work.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  alert('form submitted');
});
```

**Question**

Is there something specific in Magento that I could use with this implementation that I could hook into instead of a standard submit handler? Or a different/better way to observe a form's submit handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Prototype I was able to override the existing submit handler.

```
VarienForm.prototype.submit = VarienForm.prototype.submit.wrap(function($super, url) {
    //-- your code can go before OR after the default form behavior

    //-- include this if you want to include the previous submit behavior
    $super(url);
    return false;
});
```